# ASP.NET login form that works well with browsers 'remember password' feature

Tags: asp.net

I know this has been asked several times, but I'm not happy with the answers so far.

Root problem is the way the browsers detect a "login form" to auto-fill the fields and decide if they should ask the user to save the info.  It works fine if your form has just the basic login fields.  If the same form has lots of other fields, the browser doesn't detect it as a login form.

The solutions I've seen say to use a separate non-ASPX form on your page.  In my case all of my input fields are rather complex subclassed versions of ASPX controls, mostly to get stuff like a custom background image and nice handling of place-holder/watermark text and items of that nature.  So trying to create a non-ASPX form is a lot more work since I can't use these controls on the form.  I'd have to replicate them in standard HTML.  I could do this, but would rather not.  Plus it's more maintenance anytime I need to make a change.

**Is there a better way?  That lets me use all of the greatness that is ASP.NET.**

My page has both a login area and a register area (name, email, DOB, etc).  This is why the browsers are confused.

I seem to recall when I was writing a website for mobile browsers that there was some markup that could be used to tell the browser "this is a login name field, and this is a password field".  If something like that was available, that would be perfect.

Maybe I could do something with an iframe?  Like an ASPX page inside an ASPX page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite the complexity of your code, any custom ASP.NET user controls will eventually render **output as HTML** and every browsers only **speak HTML**

What you 're looking for is how to write ASP.NET code that results HTML mark-up containing the simple attribute..

`<input type="password" autocomplet="off" ...`

So that all browser will able to recognize it's a form containing password field. It doesn't care what you do in code behind. Focus on the output.

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't clear, but I know how to do this by writing the raw HTML.  I'm just looking for a better way, or more specifically, a more ASP.NET friendly way.  One that allows me to use the controls, because I really love ASP.NET and take full advantage of it as much as possible.